# Pycharm won't open from TightVnc viewer

Tags: pycharm, tightvnc

I am having a hard time trying to open PyCharm in TightVnc. Other products of JetBrains such as DataGrip, Intellij work.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to file an issue directly to [PyCharm bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)